# ActionbarSherlock does not include "overflow" section of Action Bar (on Android 2.1)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am developing **Android 2.1 API 7** app. To implement action bar, I am using [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library.

Everything goes fine with the **sherlock** library, I can implement action bar with it in my project with the following code.

**res/menu/action_menu.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/new_payment_1"
          android:title="@string/new_payment"       
          />    

    <item 
          android:id="@+id/label_1"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item 
          android:id="@+id/label_2"
          android:title="text2"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>

    <!-- overflow section of action bar -->
    <item android:title="title2"/>

    <item android:title="title3"/>

    <item android:title="title4"/>

</menu>
```

In my **Activity** class:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
   return true;
}
```

I got action bar successfully with above code. No problem at all on Android 3.2 platform.

**BUT the problem is** if I run my app on **Android 2.1** platform, the action bar **has no overflow section** on the Action Bar. **Why???** Anyone has experienced the same problem when using **Sherlock** library on old Android platform??

(P.S. "overflow section" of action bar is the right-most part of action bar which hides some items like a popup menu. [More info here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) )

Answer (score 10):

It uses the native options menu as overflow, just as an Ice Cream Sandwich phone would should one be made with a hardware menu key.

Forcing an overflow action item to be on the action bar on pre-4.0 devices will be a feature of version 4 of ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: Thanks, for the information. Do you know if I switch to use ActionbarCompat, will the overflow action be on the action bar on pre-3.2 devices???

Comment: No, it uses the same technique.

Comment: @ Jake, is there any way to make my app to have overflow action on the action bar on pre-3.2 device (Meanwhile using native action bar component for 3.2+ device) ?

Comment: Not with version 3. Version 4 will support this.

Comment: Thank you, and when will version 4 be released?

Comment: The first release candidate will be this evening. Final release is currently targeted at March 7th.

Comment: Thank you, so, where can I get the first release which is supposed to be in this evening?  And I can find the v4 on March 7th from official website right?

Comment: I have download version 4 but still there is problem

Comment: For those who are looking for answers: use Theme.Sherlock.*.ForceOverflow

Comment: Please DO NOT use the ForceOverflow themes. They will be removed in the next major version of the library.

Comment: @JakeWharton ..please guide me too on creating action overflow icon ... i ahve downloaded library from http://actionbarsherlock.com/ tar file ...

Answer (score 0):

Support for overflow menu for pre-Ice Cream Sandwich devices has been removed from ActionBarSherlock.  A good discussion of this can be found here: [Force overflow menu in ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179620/force-overflow-menu-in-actionbarsherlock)