# Getting the right icons for Action Bar (ActionBarSherlock) and Options Menu with Android Gingerbread

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-optionsmenu, android-icons

How do you manage Icons with ABS and Gingerbread? As you can see from the Screenshots, I have a menu item "Help", that sits in the action bar, when there's room for it. (when nothing is selected). The icon looks good so far. But when it moves into the options menu, I probably should use another icon for better visibility :)

How do you normally do that? Any ideas? This is my menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/new_button"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="new"
    android:icon="@drawable/content_new_calendar"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/share_button"
    android:visible="false"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="share"
    android:icon="@drawable/social_share"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/help_button"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="help"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_help"/>


</menu>
```

I know how to create different menus for various api levels, etc. But here, the same phone is showing the icon in the action bar and in the options menu. The simplest solution is to set android:showAsAction="never", but from user reviews I learned, that the App is difficult to understand (especially the Widget-Part), so I would love to have the help menu visible. Any ideas?

P.S. I know that the App is ugly and unfinished. It's work in progress and will be polished :)
[image: Help Icon in the Action Bar]
[image: Help Icon in the Options Menu]
[image: Help Icon in the Options Menu (Selected)]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the force overflow option like so:

```
<item name="absForceOverflow">true</item>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Seems I have to downgrade ABS to 4.1, since latest version don't allow this feature any longer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179620/force-overflow-menu-in-actionbarsherlock