# Creating a floating menu and forcing it to be hidden

Tags: java, android, android-layout, menu, android-menu

I'm writing an android app and want to create an action bar as follows:

[image]

I have tried this:

my menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/actions_saved"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_star"
          android:showAsAction="always" />

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

in my class

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_actions_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

1. Is there any way to create on all my activities beside 2 of them?
2. How do I force the star icon be aligned to left? Can I use a regular LinearLayout?
3. How do I force the settings action be in an overflow menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions seem to be fairly straight-forward and could be better understood with a brief review of [the Menu guide on d.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu).

1. You could inflate the same menu resource in all activities you desire the menu to appear in. If you want to keep the logic handling `onOptionsItemSelected()` in one place, you could consider introducing a super class or delegating the handling of some actions.
2. As per the documentation:

   > If necessary, you can re-order the menu items with the android:orderInCategory attribute in each  you need to move.
3. You have already done so with `android:showAsAction="never"`. Note that some devices use a hardware menu key; you should observe the device's preferred behavior to conceal overflow menus on these devices for a consistent user experience.

Comment: thanks. though i'm a bit confused. this xml defines both "settings" button (bottom right for galaxy devices) and also floating menu?

Comment: regarding (3) I understand that should have been enough. But yet I see no 3 dots on my action bar. nothing. Just a star icon

Comment: Does your device have a hardware menu key? If so, I believe this may be your confusion. Normally, the overflow menu appears in the action bar. On devices with a hardware menu key, the overflow menu pops up from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: so how can i force the 3 dots also to appear on my device? I don't see them with current "never" attribute

Comment: *If your problem is realted to your device has a hardware menu button*, you may want to take a look at these two questions about forcing the overflow to appear: [changing device configuration for HC+ ActionBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button) or [ActionBarSherlock-specific solution using the `Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow` theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179620/force-overflow-menu-in-actionbarsherlock). I would nevertheless discourage you from doing this, as it gives an inconsistent user experience.

Comment: regarding `android:orderInCategory` how can I create a menu item left to the application's icon on the action bar? or how to have an action bar without an application icon for only one activity?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible to place action items left of the application icon and would again discourage you from doing this. You will only be able to do this using a custom view in your action bar, or replacing the action bar altogether with something else. As for removing the action bar for an activity, you can simply provide a non-Sherlock or ActionBar theme.

Comment: `You will only be able to do this using a custom view in your action bar` i'll google this. but if you have a quick link, i'll be grateful.

Comment: You'll have to make use of [`setCustomView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(int)).