# Android Manifest.xml file Error : Android

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

Im having a issue with Android Manifest.xml and i have no idea what causing this. actionBarSherlock library is  correctly added but still im getting this error

" error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/
 Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow') ".

I have tried cleaning and building it but still same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under your `res/values/styles.xml` you need to add the Style: `Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow`

```
"If you are using Version 4.2.0, then .ForceOverflow themes have in fact been removed."
```

See this answer:

**[Force overflow menu in ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179620/force-overflow-menu-in-actionbarsherlock)**