# how to place an icon on the rightside of the screen to open navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, swipe-gesture

1. i am developing an chat app in that there are two navigation drawer
2. Left side drawer has hamburger icon to open and close
3. i want to place an icon in the right side of the screen so that when the user touches icon the navigation drawer will open like in android emulator there is small icon extending to the navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

**Use `menu items` like below:**

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/workteamaction"
        android:icon="@drawable/yourimage"
        android:title="@string/yourtitle"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

And set your image.then, handle it for showing that `NavigationDrawer`.

Also, take a look:

[Two Navigation Drawer on same Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921274/two-navigation-drawer-on-same-activity)

[Handling a Menu Item Click Event - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479992/handling-a-menu-item-click-event-android)

Also, i've saw one application was using `OveflowMenu` for opening another `NavigationDrawer`.you may want to take a look at here :

[Android create custom overflow menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937520/android-create-custom-overflow-menu-item)

**Edit:**

> i want to place an icon in the right side of the screen so that when
>   the user touches icon the navigation drawer will open like in android
>   emulator there is small icon extending to the navigation drawer

**Use [`android:gravity=""`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)** for your porpuse and then handle it for showing that `NavigationDrawer`.

E.g: `android:gravity="end"`

Read the docs for the flags.(right-left-center-buttom or etc).

Comment: sorry..i asked how to add icon or image in the middle of right side end of screen ..So that when the user touches right side navigation drawer will open